# Prove that $X_{n}$ converges in probability and distribution to $X$.

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics, weak-convergence

I´m learning about convergency in probability of a family of random variables. I think I´m not understanding the concept very well, because I can apply it on an exercise when $X_{n}$ converges to a constant $"c"$. But I have trouble when $X(\omega) \ne c$.

This is the exercise: Suppose that $P(X=1)=P(X=-1)=\frac {1}{2}$. Being also:

$X_{n} =
  \begin{cases}
    X      & \quad \text{with probability } 1-1/n \\
    e^n  & \quad \text{with probablity } 1/n 
  \end{cases}
$

Prove that $X_{n}$ converges in probability and distribution to $X$.

If you are able to prove that $X_{n}$ converges  in probability then it also converges in distribution.

$X$ is distributed discrete uniform with the range $\{-1,1\}$.
The definition of convergency in probability is $X_{n}$ converges in probability to $X$ if $P(|X_{n}(\omega)-X|>\epsilon)$ tends to $0$ when $n$ tends to $\infty$.

Comment: Hint: For any $\varepsilon > 0$ and $n \in \mathbb N_+$, you have $\{|X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| > \varepsilon\} \subset \{ X_n(\omega) \neq X(\omega)\}$.

Comment: Is this okay? $P(|Xn(ω)−X|>ϵ)=P(-ϵ<X_{n}(ω)−X<ϵ)=P(-ϵ+X<X_{n}(ω)<ϵ+X)=F_{X_{n}}(X+ϵ)-F_{X_{n}}(X-ϵ)$

Comment: But then, the distribution function of $X_{n}$ only depends of the value of $n$. So just constructing the distribution function and taking limits to infinity then it is proved? Or with this you can only prove convergency in distribution?

Comment: It doesn't technically make sense to write it in terms of $F_{X_n}$ because $X$ depends on $\omega$ as well. Basically you have the probability of a random variable to lie in a random interval which is not in general expressible in terms of only the CDF of the random variable alone. Instead you can use what Dominik Kutek said to get an inequality, since $A \subset B \Rightarrow P(A) \leq P(B)$, and you already know $P(X_n=X)$.

Comment: $P(X_{n}≠X)=1-(1-1/n)$ ( the complement of $P(X_{n}=X)$). So then taking limits to infinity $P(X_{n}≠X)=0$ when n tends to infinity. Am I headed right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thank you. You were very helpful!